# Репозитории и DRY

Tags: php, dry

вопрос по репозиторям, их аналогам и DRY.
Берем простой пример:

```
$articles = $articleRepository->getByCategory(Category $category);
```

По правилам хорошего кода, нужно указывать поля для выборки, никак не * . В одном месте может понадобиться 2 поля, в другом 3, в третьем вообще только id.
И тут возникает проблема, как это организовать по DRY и без проблем с неймингом ? Ведь это явно не вариант:

```
$articles = $articleRepository->getFullListByCategory(Category $category);

$articles = $articleRepository->getShortListByCategory(Category $category);
```

Или Передавать поля в виде массива вторым параметром?

```
$articleRepository->getByCategory(Category $category, array $columns = ['id','name']);
```

А если будет разница только в сортировках? Или Limit? 
Причем ладно тут запрос будет легкий. А представим какой-нибудь сложный запрос, у которого будут только order by в конце отличаться, или поля select. Это же будет большое количество повторений, да и проблемы с неймингом.

```
getByCategoryIdAsc(), getByCategoryIdDesc(), getByCategoryIdAscNameDesc()
```

Как на счет варианта ко всем малоотличающимся запросам добавлять возможность объекта Criteria который устанавливает простые правила select, order, offset, limit?

```
$criteria =  (new Criteria())->select(['id','name'])->orderBy('id','asc');
$articles = $articleRepository->getByCategory(Category $category, criteria);
```

Или это нарушает правила репозитория?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, задача репозитория - отдать данные по запросу, который не имеет отношения к реализации самого репозитория. SQL это или может быть простое файловое хранилище, или может быть из конфига что берет.

Когда вы составляете подобные `criteria` - вы как будто пишете sql, что означает только одну реализацию репозитория.

Подавляющее большинство репозиториев в наших проектах выглядят примерно так:

```
interface IRepository
{
  public function getItem($filter = null);
  public function getList($filter = null);
  public function getCount($filter = null);
  ...
}
```

То есть есть лишь один метод для получения одного элемента, один метод для получения списка и тд. Есть конечно исключения.

`$filter` - это параметры выборки, включает "человекопонятные" условия. Может быть объект или массив или что-нибудь еще.

Как применить эти условия - решает репозиторий внутри себя.

Пример использования:

```
$articles = $articleRepository->getList([
  'category' => $category
]);
$articles = $articleRepository->getList([
  'category' => $category,
  'sort' => 'asc'
]);
$articles = $articleRepository->getList([
  'category' => $category,
  'another_field' => $value,
  'sort' => 'superspecialsort', // в репозитории строится супер ORDER BY
  'limit' => 20,
  'dataset' => 'short' // репозиторий знает какие это поля
]);
```

Переданный фильтр строится для всех методов, getItem, getList, getCount и тд.

Не сильно вижу смысл перечислять какие вам поля нужно от репозитория. Только если в табличке есть очень тяжелые поля которые вам не нужны, но в этом случае можно обойтись dataset=short|full. Если вам нужны только 2 поля, то вы просто их потом и используете.

Comment: Но разве составляя такие глубокие фильтры, тем более массивы, мы не ломаем логику построения от интерфейса?  Т.е. мы строим новый репозиторий, смотрим интерфейс - а там только getlist. Откуда мы будем знать, что там нужно использовать another_field ?

Comment: @Pavel, лучше пусть фильтр будет регламентирован, чем помещать логику фильтрации в название метода. PhpDoc может помочь сделать фильтрацию прозрачнее.

Comment: @Pavel, попробуйте накидать интерфейсы компонентов и посмотрите на ситуацию со стороны. Как вам будет понятнее так и делайте. Лучше сделать и понять в чем ошибка, чем ломать голову. Ломать голову конечно не плохо, но не очень долго)))  Если посмотреть репозитории компонентов на гитхабе - они все полны гайдов и инструкций. Я крайне редко смотрю в интерфейсы того что там делают люди, если е ть инструкции. И если вы делаете комплексное приложение, а не компонент, то скорее всего репозитории будут иметь схожую структуру и новый человек сможет понять устройство без проблем.